# git intellij revert commit

Tags: git, intellij-idea

On intelliJ - I want to revert a commit- the commit contains both added and modified files ,

so I'm selecting the commit in the history, right click and press "Revert"-

this will pop up the commit dialog with both deleted files and modified files.

**The deleted files are un-checked by default** (only the modified files are checked)- this can lead problems in case user doesn't pay attention to what is checked or unchecked.

**Is there a way to make the deleted files be checked by default?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works fine for me in 2018.1 and 2018.2. What version do you use? It could be some bug that is already fixed.